# Touchpad on a Fujitsu Lifebook a532

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, multi-touch

My touchpad is not working as it should. Well, it works but cant use 2-finger scroll.

I get this:

```
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ xinput --list
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
PS/2 Generic Mouse                          id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

How to enable 2-fingerscroll and a proper driver?

Comment: No one that know how I can get my Alps touchpad to work properly in 12.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by myself. Installing Dell Alps Driver seems to work. Also needed to install gpointing-device-settings to be able set correct speed on the sensitive since the one in system-settings didn't do anything.

Everything work now, and xinput give me this:

```
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ xinput | grep point
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Worked on Fujitsu AH552**

**Steps**

Find the device name

```
xinput list
```

in my case it is
**AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint**

then find the current values for the device

```
xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" | grep -i finger
```

**In my case it was 12, 15, 0**

next we have to change the values as per below

**12, 12, 0**

for that we can use below command

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Finger" 12, 12, 0
```

Now the touch pad will be normal and also side scrolling should be working.

Finally we have to save the changes permanently, other wise this will not work after rebooting.

**Create a bash file**

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/fujitsu-lifebook-ah552-alps-touc-pad-settings.sh
```

the first line of the text should be this

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and after two line paste the command we previously used for changing the values.

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint" "Synaptics Finger" 12, 12, 0
```

save the file using shortcut ctrl+o, then exit ctrl+x

**make the file executable**

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/fujitsu-lifebook-ah552-alps-touc-pad-settings.sh
```

That's all! Do not forget to reboot the machine!

**Disable two finger scrolling on mouse setting to enable side scrolling.**