# Touchpad on Fujiitsu Lifebook AH532 not working correctly

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, alps, fujitsu-siemens

Ubuntu 13.10, Fujitsu Lifebook AH532

Touchpad appearing as PS/2 Mouse under xinput --list, so no multi-touch or scroll support or anything like that.

Have tried installing alternate driver as described [on launchpad,](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1041916) specifically in [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1041916/comments/14)

but it fails on the build step;

```
sudo dkms build psmouse/alps-dst-1.0)
```

with

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-1.0/build/make.log for more information.
```

make.log mentioned contains the following:

```
DKMS make.log for psmouse-alps-dst-1.0 for kernel 3.11.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Sun Mar  2 14:17:16 GMT 2014
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-1.3/build/src/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-1.3/build/src/Makefile'. Stop.
make: *** [psmouse.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
```

I've also seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283812/touchpad-on-a-fujitsu-lifebook-a532)

That says installing Dell ALPS driver worked.. but after much searching of how to do this, and trying a few different things, I've had no luck with that either. Maybe a slightly different model/ubuntu version?

Any help greatly appreciated, I'm stumped!

Comment: I know it isn't much help to you directly but I am literally just after succeding to get my touchpad working with the [first link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1041916/comments/14) you posted on my fujitsu lifebook ah532 so don't give up hope on it. Thanks for posting this because without it I'd still be stuck without it working, so this was as good as a solution for me and hopefully for others with the same laptop and distro that find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

after unpacking the driver to /usr/src/psmouse-alps-dst-1.0/ I edited the make config files in the source and build directories to reflect the location.

They currently say "alps-1.3", which I changed to "alps-dst-1.0" in the config files.

The driver then builds and installs correctly.